# Where to place log4j.xml

Tags: log4j

How can we specify where log4j has to look at when trying to find its xml configuration file?

It seems that, by default, log4j looks into the root of a class folder, I can say that using the debug log4j functionality and running my application from the IDE.

However, I don't have any class folder in my jar anymore. And the log4j.xml file is at the root of the jar.

I have already tried to set the option -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml but it doesn't work.

Here is the global structure of my application at the moment:

- com
- lib
- meta-inf
- log4j.xml

Comment: when using log4j 2.0 or more, the file name should be 'log4j2.xml'

Answer (score 39):

It finds the log4j.xml using the CLASSPATH.  If log4j doesn't find any config file, it will send an error to the console.  If you don't see any such error then it is likely that it is finding a config file which may not be the one you are editing.  There is a command-line option to force Log4J to report the path of the config file it is using.

From http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jConfigurationHelp

> If you run with "-Dlog4j.debug" then
>   log4j will print out info to standard
>   output telling how it is trying to
>   configure itself. Looking through that
>   will tell you where it is looking for
>   the config file.

Comment: Log4j.xml is at the root of my folder. And this folder is included into my classpath. However, it doesn't seem to be picked up by log4j ... :/

Comment: I am aware of this debugging functionnality, but it doesn't seem to be working. The log are just printed out on the console, and I don't see any debug log. I don't have any error... I'm totally lost.

Comment: If the debug parm doesn't make Log4J report the path and filename of the config file being loaded, I'd wonder about how the application was being started.  Is this through a batch file? What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 25):

Suppose your log4j configuration is outside the source tree. If it can't find your configuration file, help it with:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///your/path/log4j.xml
```

Note the qualifier **file:///**. It won't work without.

Comment: hi rwst: I want to load laback.xml from tomcat vm argument but this is not working, can u suggest any Idea?

Comment: This answer along with -Dlog4j.debug option is perfect for figuring out what is happening.

Comment: Great answer! Was searching for something like that as I wanted to have the configuration file in a custom path!

Answer (score 8):

May be this is very old question, but for me the answer was in the official Log4j 2 documentation:

> #### [Automatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Automatic_Configuration)
>
> Log4j has the ability to *automatically* configure itself during
> initialization. When Log4j starts it will locate all the
> `ConfigurationFactory` plugins and arrange them in weighted order from
> highest to lowest. As delivered, Log4j contains four
> `ConfigurationFactory` implementations: one for JSON, one for YAML, one for properties, and one for XML.
>
> 1. Log4j will inspect the `"log4j2.configurationFile"` system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the
>    `ConfigurationFactory` that matches the file extension. Note that this
>    is not restricted to a location on the local file system and may
>    contain a URL.
> 2. If no system property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for
>    `log4j2-test.properties` in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for
>    `log4j2-test.yaml` or `log4j2-test.yml` in the classpath.
> 4. If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for
>    `log4j2-test.json` or `log4j2-test.jsn` in the classpath.
> 5. If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for
>    `log4j2-test.xml` in the classpath.
> 6. If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for `log4j2.properties` on the classpath.
> 7. If a properties file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for `log4j2.yaml` or `log4j2.yml` on the classpath.
> 8. If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for `log4j2.json` or `log4j2.jsn` on the classpath.
> 9. If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate `log4j2.xml` on the classpath.
> 10. If no configuration file could be located the `DefaultConfiguration` will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

Comment: would you know if I can put an .xml file in a subfolder or nested subfolder of the resources folder? I can't figure out how to load it with `"log4j.configurationFile"` ... I can only get it to load from the root resources folder, what am I doing wrong? (note to me: #163489028)

Answer (score 5):

> I don't have any error

So log4j is finding your configuration, otherwise you would get:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger ().
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Also:

> The log are just printed out on the console

So that means that you probably need to define a file appender, like [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html) or [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html). The "Configuration" section on [the short intro](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) has a few examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```java
DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jConfigurationFilename);
```

and specify the location if it is other than the root.

Answer (score -1):

Do not worry about where to put it. Just run your project, say in eclipse, log4j will throw an exception, telling you where it was looking. Then you can put it there.

Once you get it working, you will also figure out how to change that, as you understand the logic.

Comment: In eclipse there is an exception thrown, but it does not tell you where it is looking for the file.

Comment: Console-Output says: "ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging." So not helpfull, sorry.

Comment: Indeed, this is pretty robust. Just give it a try. I put it in my IntelliJ Idea project in the folder `src/main/resources` without any further configuration.