# When is it necessary to call DOMConfigurator.configure to read a log4j.xml file?

Tags: java, log4j

I am learning how to use **log4j** (with **slf4j**) in a Java project. Some web pages I have read say to call `DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml")` to incorporate the settings in the `log4j.xml` file into a `Logger` you have created.

I have also seen plenty of code examples where a `log4j.xml` file and some Java code are presented, and the Java code does not call `DOMConfigurator.configure`. The descriptions around the code samples imply that the `log4j.xml` settings are getting picked up by the logger.

In my project, if I don't call `DOMConfigurator.configure`, the `log4j.xml` file is not read. Are there conventions for when a `log4j.xml` file will be found when `getLogger` is called, and loading the file explicitly with `DOMConfigurator.configure` is not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

What if log4j.xml wasnt at the root of the class path? That's the convention. If it's at the root of the class path of the current classloader, you don't need to do a thing

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772466/where-to-place-log4j-xml) for some information. Also, try running java with -Dlog4.debug ([as discussed here)](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2006/07/know-how-log4j-tries-to-configure.html)