# Setting up logs using log4j for a scheduled batch program (console application)

Tags: java, logging, log4j

What is the best way to configure log4j for a console application purely in Java.Where exactly we need to place log4j.xml ?

Comment: Have you tried configuring and placing it somewhere?

Comment: I'm using eclipse IDE. I have created a folder called logs in the same project

Comment: What is your project strucute, where have you placed the log4j properties/xml file. What are the contents of your log4j proeprites/xml file.

Comment: DataMigration/src DataMigration/Jars DataMigration/logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For automatic configuration the log4j configuration file should be on the root of the classpath, e.g. packaged in your .jar on the top level.

There is also a environment variable to specify the location `-Dlog4j.configuration=...`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772466/where-to-place-log4j-xml) may help you further.

If your application is exclusively used standalone, putting the config inside the .jar should be ok. But note, that this causes trouble and hard to find misconfigurations if that .jar is used in context of another application, e.g. a web application. I would suggest to distribute the console application as a bundle with a starting script and the log config outside the .jar.