# Why does Log4J2 stop after log4j2-test.xml and not continue to look for log4j2.xml?

Tags: java, log4j2

I have 2 apps that are both looking for log4j2.xml.  One finds it and one doesn't.

After adding this to the jvm:  -Dlog4j.debug (using 2.11.2 of everything)

The first app that runs correctly scans and finds the file:

[image]

The second app stops scanning after log4j2-test.xml

I [image]

When I add log4j2-test.xml to the second app, it finds it and works correctly.  Obviously there is a difference (the apps are VERY similar) but can't find it.  Any ideas?  What would cause Log4j2 to stop scanning for the property file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200891/how-to-use-multiple-configuration-files-for-log4j2

Comment: Yup.  Saw that.  Doesn't answer my quesition.  I don't want to use two files.

Comment: Did you add log42.xml in src/java/resources and similarly src/test/resources ?

Comment: No, it is only src/java/resources

Comment: log4j2-test.xml should be added for src/test/resources, because it will be used for unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the order used by Log4j2 to look for configuration.

> 1. Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.
> 2. If no system property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.properties in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.yaml or log4j2-test.yml in the classpath.
> 4. If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.json or log4j2-test.jsn in the classpath.
> 5. **If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.xml in the classpath.**
> 6. If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.properties on the classpath.
> 7. If a properties file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.yaml or log4j2.yml on the classpath.
> 8. If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.json or log4j2.jsn on the classpath.
> 9. **If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.**
> 10. If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

Reference: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration

Comment: You are correct.  I could not find the log4j2-test.xml anywhere, but it must be finding one somewhere.  Thanks for the help!