# Where should I put the configuration files?

Tags: java, jar, config

I have a jar library `A` where they read the configuration from a file like this:

```
    public static void init(){      
        DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
    }
```

I am using library `A` in project `B` which will eventually be added as a jar to the web app `C`. 
(I am *trying* to use maven for the project `B`)

So I have something like this:

In project `B`

```
projB/
  log4j.xml
  /src
  /lib
     A.jar //needs log4j.xml
```

In webapp `C`

```
war/
  WEB-INF/
    lib/
      A.jar
      B.jar  //has log4j.xml
```

When I test `C.war` in my local server it complains that

```
log4j:ERROR Could not parse file [log4j.xml].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.../SERVER_FOLDER/log4j.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Is it possible to make `A` read the file from inside the WAR?

Comment: You run your program from some directory, it's your "working directory", all the relative paths are calculated from it.

Comment: It depends on what DOMConfigurator.configure() does.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Except if it doesn't use file IO to read the file, but the ClassLoader's getResource().

Comment: Read this [duplicate post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772466/where-to-place-log4j-xml) as well and let me know if the post is not useful in this context.

Comment: To remove all the doubts, OP should just use method with `URL` passed. For example, if he wants to read this file from current jar or classes file tree, he should you just `DOMConfigurator.configure(this.getClass().getResource("log4j.xml"))` (at the same level, as this class)

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg I cannot change how they read "log4j.xml" in the library.

Comment: @elisa.zc yes, you can't, but there's another static method, which receive `URL`