# Problems setting up LogEntries on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, log4j, google-cloud-endpoints, logentries

I'm trying to [setup logentries](https://logentries.com/doc/java/) on App Engine backend **Java** on Android Studio

I keep getting this error message whatever I did

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (root).
>
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>
> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Here's my file structure

[image: File structure in Android Studio]

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,le
log4j.appender.le=com.logentries.log4j.LogentriesAppender
log4j.appender.le.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.le.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ} %-5p: %F:%L  %m
log4j.appender.le.Token=HIDDEN
log4j.appender.le.Debug=True
log4j.appender.le.Ssl=False
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="le" class="com.logentries.log4j.LogentriesAppender">
        <param name="Token" value="HIDDEN"/>
        <param name="Ssl" value="false"/>
        <param name="Debug" value="true"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy}, (%F:%L) %-5p: %m"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="example">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="debug"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="le"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>HIDDEN/application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties"/>
        <property name="log4j.configuration" value="WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties"/>
        <property name="gcm.api.key" value="HIDDEN"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

---

**Update**

I found a very helpful tip in this question [Where to place log4j.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772466/where-to-place-log4j-xml), basically put -Dlog4j.debug in the Java VM arguments and run App Engine in debug mode. It told me exactly whether it found log4j.xml or not. After much trial and error, It found it when I put it under WEB-INF/classes, now I can see precisely the full stack trace of the error I am having

```
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader@560cbf1a.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/_Folder/_Code/AppNameHidden/backend/build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "true".
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [example] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for example is  [debug].
log4j: example level set to DEBUG
log4j: Level value for root is  [debug].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [com.logentries.log4j.LogentriesAppender]
log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:454)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:508)
    at com.logentries.net.AsyncLogger$SocketAppender.<init>(AsyncLogger.java:496)
    at com.logentries.net.AsyncLogger.<init>(AsyncLogger.java:336)
    at com.logentries.net.AsyncLogger.<init>(AsyncLogger.java:343)
    at com.logentries.log4j.LogentriesAppender.<init>(LogentriesAppender.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:247)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at hello.edu.appnamehidden.backend.RegistrationEndpoint.<clinit>(RegistrationEndpoint.java:36)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.getClassForName(ServletInitializationParameters.java:82)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.fromServletConfig(ServletInitializationParameters.java:51)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.init(SystemServiceServlet.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
log4j: Appender named [le] not found.
Dec 31, 2014 1:50:36 AM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet init
INFO: SPI restricted: true
log4j: Finalizing appender named [null].
```

---

**Working workaround solution**

Thanks to @MarkLC help I was able to get LogEntries working on the local machine, check the answer and comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/27688486/546439, however, this never worked on the deployed App Engine.

I had to resort to using this gist https://gist.github.com/anlcan/9348751 and modifying it a little bit, it worked perfectly with App Engine when deployed.

Here's my code

```
public class LogEntriesHelper
{
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    private static final String LOG_TOKEN = "HIDDEN";

    public static void log(String message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (socket == null || !socket.isConnected())
            {
                if (lock.tryLock())
                {
                    socket = new Socket("data.logentries.com", 10000);
                    condition.signalAll();
                    lock.unlock();
                }
                else
                {
                    condition.await();
                }
            }

            Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
            out.write(LOG_TOKEN);
            out.write(" ");
            out.write(message);
            out.write("\r\n");
            out.flush();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to place your config, either the xml or the properties inside src/main/resources for it to be picked up by log4j. You can just create that resources folder alongside java and webapp. Your config looks fine. Hope that helps.

### Update

After looking into App Engines sandbox, it seems it doesn't allow threads that outlive the request that spawned it. Your stack trace shows a RuntimePermission issue as that library spawns a background thread to send the log events to Logentries asynchronously. So this comes down to this library not being compatible with AppEngines sandbox.

You should be able to use log4j's built-in SyslogAppender to send logs synchronously to Logentries. I've successfully tested this locally but not from AppEngines sandbox with the below log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, syslog
log4j.appender.syslog=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.syslog.Facility=LOCAL7
log4j.appender.syslog.SyslogHost=api.logentries.com:10000
log4j.appender.syslog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.syslog.layout.ConversionPattern=SECRET_TOKEN%p: (%F:%L) %x %m %n
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. That is a wrong answer I am afraid. I found a very helpful tip in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772466/where-to-place-log4j-xml. I've put the log4j.xml under WEB-INF/classes. I'll update the question to show the new error log

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, haven't been online past few days, just updated my answer there. Your issue is due to AppEngine's sandbox but you should be able to use built-in SyslogAppender as it wont spin up its own thread.

Comment: No worries I'll try that right now and let you know straight away. I really need to fix this issue more than anything else in the world

Comment: just a quick clarification, will I be using Token TCP or Plain TCP, UDP ?

Comment: MarkLC also why are you putting the SECRET_TOKEN in the ConverstionPattern ?

Comment: I should have been more specific. The value you passed to LogentriesAppender for Token param needs to be placed in the ConversionPattern where I have SECRET_TOKEN, this way we're able to use the Token TCP Logentries input as opposed to Plain TCP, all Token TCP is, is regular TCP but with each message prefixed by a log token for routing purposes, that token is stripped out when the message is received so won't show up in Logentries UI when viewing logs.

Comment: where should I place the log4j.properties file ? and in appengine-web.xml should I place  <system-properties><property name="log4j.configuration" value="WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties"/> is that correct ?

Comment: You can place the new log4j.properties file in WEB-INF/classes/ as you did before, as we know it was detected correctly in there and keep the same system-property as you mentioned. Is it still not working?

Comment: for some reason it's not finding the log4j.properties file and giving me these logs log4j: Trying to find [WEB-INF/log4j.properties] using context classloader com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader@4cc547a.
log4j: Trying to find [WEB-INF/log4j.properties] using com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader@4cc547a class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [WEB-INF/log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [WEB-INF/log4j.properties].

Comment: I'll remove the property name="log4j.configuration and try again, cause I didn't have that the first time

Comment: I had to remove the property name="log4j.configuration" for it to work

Comment: Great. Glad it worked for you. Thats interesting about the system.property. maybe a path issue in the value.

Comment: I'm afraid I have bad news :((((( it works perfectly on my local machine, in both Debug and Run modes, but it doesn't when I deploy, I tried everything including putting the log4j.properties file in resources and all. It's giving me this error .<stderr>: log4j:ERROR Failed to write [<188>da6289d3-1b4d-43ec-9f97-d9ce051dd9e4WARN: (MessagingEndpoint.java:54)  sendMessage called 
      ].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68080/discussion-between-dv-mh-and-marklc).