# using slf4j with log4j

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I am having a problem with slf4j with log4j.

I have a log4j.xml on development environment and it is set to DEBUG.

In my pom.xml I have the following:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

When I run my code and I use Logger (SLF4J) and I check whether debug is enabled - I get false and if anyway I try to log.debug I don't see the result.

but, if in the same class I use Logger (apache log4j) everything works well as I expect.

I read many posts about the log4j and slf4j but I could not solve it.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like log4j is not finding / reading your "log4j.xml" file.  Focus on that.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772466/where-to-place-log4j-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found a hint and fixed the problem. I add to change the pom to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The mistake was I used slf4j-simple instead of slf4j-log4j12.

Thanks

Comment: According to [slf4j Manual](http://slf4j.org/manual.html), **Declaring project dependencies for logging** "If you wish to use log4j as the underlying logging framework, all you need to do is to declare "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12" as a dependency in your pom.xml file as shown below. In addition to slf4j-log4j12-1.7.28.jar, this will pull slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar as well as log4j-1.2.17.jar into your project."